# customize the background of ControlsFX Notification

Tags: javafx

How can I change the white background to green background in java or css?

The Notification class does not have `getStylesheet()` method.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xmd3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider using a JavaFX [Alert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) instead of a ControlsFX Notification. An `Alert` has a `DialogPane` which implements the `Styleable` interface, and has a `getStylesheets` method.

So to use it you would have something like

```
Alert myAlert = new Alert(AlertType.NONE);
myAlert.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add("myStylesheet.css");
```

Comment: sure, I created a chat room here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162919/customize-the-background-of-controlsfx-notification